# Difference of the three lambda function definitions (handler.js)

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I see different examples of skeleton function definitions in handler.js when I play with [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/). In `handler.js`

1. Version 1: `module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {...}`;
2. Version 2: `module.exports.store = async event => {...}`
3. Version 3: `module.exports.store = (event, context, callback) =>  {...}`

Version 1 and Version 2 are similar in the way that they are both defined as async function and the only difference is number of parameters, but why can Version 2 ignore context entirely? I assume the API-Gateway will pass the context parameter to the lambda function anyway, how can the lambda function not define the argument? (won't this cause run time error during lambda invocation?)

Version 3 is defined in an entirely different paradigm, i.e., not an async function, and I think this this the skeleton function generated by an older version Serverless framework.

Can someone give me some guide here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference between versions 1/2 and version 3 is JS syntax. Version 1/2 use more modern `async/await` syntax. Version 3 is older, and uses callbacks. You can read about more of the differences here: https://medium.com/@ThatGuyTinus/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-async-await-f65ed7c2b9b4

As you noted, the only difference between Versions 1 and 2 is the `Context` object. This is provided by AWS, and includes helpful lambda-specific attributes and methods like `getRemainingTimeInMillis()`, which tells you how much longer your function can execute.

You can read more about that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

I'd say that most people are using Version 1 these days.